# How to remove persistent 'app is running in the background' notification from an app?Is firebase causing the problem?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, notifications, foreground-service

I am working on a [project](https://github.com/StealthViper/WashKaro) and whenever we run the app we get a notification `App is running in background` and even when the app is killed it just stays there. The app uses data from Firebase and also has a Bluetooth Service so I am not sure which one is causing the problem.

The notification comes **as soon as the app is launched**. I would have provided blocks of code but I am unable to narrow it down hence didn't know which part to include. The notification may become a major cause of uninstalling if the app is released thus any input in removing it will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Do you have some kind of service running within the app?

Comment: Yes there are BLE services and Firebase services being used within the app

Comment: Are those foreground services?

Comment: Yes the bluetooth service also sends a notification to the user on the basis of contact tracing. I'm not sure what foreground exactly is but I think this would count